# In Ubuntu, is there any terminal that allows for the position of the cursor to be moved with the mouse?

Tags: gnome-terminal

For example, if I find I miss one letter in a long command, currently I need to press ← to move the cursor, which is slow.
Why can't we use mouse to put the cursor in the place we want?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl - left or Ctrl - right?

Comment: Thank. I knew it. I hope a more flexible move. I think the mouse is much more convenient. I find the python console in PyCharm is as friendly as an editor. But how about other terminals?

Comment: I would love to know if this was possible with gnome-terminal. Apparently you can do so in OSX: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7051091.

Comment: For native terminal, you will probably have no luck. See the [mouse section](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Text-Terminal-HOWTO/#ss9.9) in the terminal howto of *The Linux Documentation Project*.

Answer (score 8):

Use emacs.

```
sudo apt-get install emacs
```

Upon the install, start emacs:
`emacs`

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, and type `term` and press Enter. Voila!

You have a terminal where you can change the cursor position with mouse.

If mouse click does not change the cursor (in 99% of the cases, it will, by default), then put (xterm-mouse-mode t) in your .emacs file:

```
echo (xterm-mouse-mode t) > ~/.emacs
```

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be a way with gnome-terminal, this seems like the easiest method.

Comment: I just tried the method. The mouse click does not change the cursor. Then as instructed, I put: echo (xterm-mouse-mode t) > ~/.emacs; The error information is:  bash: syntax error near unexpected token `xterm-mouse-mode' (I use Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 4):

The terminal itself can take mouse input. You can test this opening a text file with `nano` and enabling mouse

```
(M-M)                   Mouse support enable/disable
```

(On my keyboard that's <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.)

Then you can change the position of the cursor by clicking.
If you are asking about changing the position of cursor in the SHELL, there was a discussion in [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2118470) mentioning *gpm*. There is also a duplicate of this question in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966903/how-to-get-mousemove-and-mouseclick-in-bash) with some alternatives proposed.

Comment: The question is about the shell, specifically moving the cusor position (since you can easily select text with the mouse, for instance, in gnome-terminal).

Comment: why the downvote? The original question was a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "\e[?1000;1006;1015h" # Enable mouse tracking
```

Script : I made a bash script to move bash readline cursor on mouse click on my [github](https://github.com/tinmarino/mouse_xterm/blob/master/mouse.sh)

Details : Read my answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55437976/2544873)

Answer (score 0):

In vi mode (when the the command line behave as vi, enabled by `set -o vi`) you can launch a full vi to edit the current line:
Pass in command mode with `ESC`, then press `v`. and in vi you should be able to use your mouse to move to the expect character.

I don't know if this kind of command exist for the emacs mode (`set -o emacs`), the default one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jupyter qtconsole`](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole) with the [bash_kernel](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel) to accomplish this! Follow the install instructions at github repos in the links provided, then from the terminal run

`jupyter console --kernel bash`

This will launch an new window with a versatile and powerful shell that has

- mouse cursor positioning
- text selection and editing
- autocomplete
- history
- so much more